# Importing Excel into Access, error row number reported by Access does not match with row number in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, import-from-excel

I have done this many times and have never seen this. I have an Excel file that I am importing into Access. In this process, if Access encounters some errors, it stores these error incidences in a table called **ImportErrors**. This table shows the error (eg. "*Type Conversion Failure*"), the field on which the error was encountered, and the row on which the error was encountered. These row numbers match up nicely with the row numbers in the Excel file as well as the newly created table in Access, and it is very easy to track down and correct the erroneous entry.

This time, Access reported it encountered errors in rows 1637, 1782, and 2453.

Rows 1637 and 2453 match up nicely in both Excel and Access, but row 1782 matches in the Excel file, but not in the Access table! The row shows up as row 1810 in Access, while it is row 1782 in Excel!

I'm baffled, this has never happened to me before and I cannot think of a reason why Access would mix up rows. I began checking row-for-row and saw that access has reordered certain rows. Why?

Comment: I'm asking access to create its own autoincrement primary key for me during import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading Remou's comment, I inserted an extra column at the beginning in the excel worksheet and numbered it in series from 1.

Importing into access after this didn't cause any reordering of rows.